# spring security user requested login

Tags: jsf, spring-security

Is it possible to invoke login explicitly by user? User clicks the button and spring redirects him to login page.

Problem:
If the login button redirects to protected page (that invokes login ... let it be /login), then the request will be cached and the original context is lost.

Solutions with cons:
I don't want to change the link so it will work as entry point because then I have to copy the address. 
It's possible to throw AuthenticationException but this is logged in my logs by JSF.

Comment: I can't quite follow what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution with using address same as in EntryPoint is probably the easiest and it can be optimized if the EntryPoint is registered as bean - so I can use it directly and make the link same as in EntryPoint.